# How do I say "How is it going"

Tags: verbs, questions

I find this expression very useful, when, for example, I am talking with people I haven't been in touch with for some time.

> How is school going?
>   How is your project going?

I've seen others use *Kiel iras...?* or *Gxi iras bone*, but I doubt this is good use of the verb *iras*. Can *iri* be used in this figurative way? What are some other options?

Comment: Perhaps you can consider the (horrific) translation that appeared in the cartoon "Danny Phantom", *kiel estas ĝi iri":  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBqLd5_nio4#t=7m16s

Answer (score 4):

The expression *Kiel vi fartas?* can be used for the almost identical phrases *How are you?* and *How is it going?*

On the other hand, using *iri* for that purpose is also possible. According to [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/#iri), the eighth meaning of *iri* allows the following sentence:

> Kiel iras via komercaĵo?

It means something like *how is your business progressing?*

Comment: *Kiel vi fartas* works for the fixed expression "How is it going?", but I was looking for something more adaptable, which you anwer in the bottom part. I edited my question to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

*Iri* can be used, but I'd suggest:

> *Kiel prosperas...?* How is... going? (lit., prospering, succeeding [in])

and to make it more adaptable:

> *Kiel prosperas al vi la laboro, tiu projekto, ktp...?* How is your work, that project, etc, going?
>
> *Ĉu vi prosperas loĝi sola?* Are you managing fine, living on your own?

Zamenhof used *prosperi* + (verb) in this way:

> *ĉu prosperos al la homoj veni al interkonsento pri tiu ĉi elekto?* (Fundamenta Krestomatio)

It even appears in the New Testament:

> *Amato, mi preĝas, ke al vi prosperu ĉio, kaj vi bonsanu tiel same, kiel prosperas al via animo.* (3 Johano 1:2)

Comment: Using _iri_ makes the sentence seem Italian (_Come va?_ where _va_ is the Present Tense of Italian for _go_, third person singular). I prefer too using _prosperi_, even if this could just be a style matter.